# simple shell script to delete posts from db

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

Trying to run a shell script to delete posts from a wordpress database. At the moment it is just outputting the mysql syntax help screen. I was wondering if someone could help me debug this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u ***** -p***** admin-wp "SELECT * FROM admin_wp.wp_8_posts LIMIT 0, 10
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30" << EOFMYSQL
```

Comment: did you try input your command manually?

Comment: I guess you are missing -D switch before admin-wp  i.e. your correct syntax should be #!/bin/bash
mysql -u ***** -p***** -D admin-wp "SELECT * FROM admin_wp.wp_8_posts LIMIT 0, 10
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30" << EOFMYSQL

Comment: closer now...gives me an error 1102 incorrect database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're putting the query in the command line, you introduce it with the `-e` option, and you don't need `<<EOFMYSQL`.

```
mysql -u ***** -p***** admin-wp -e "SELECT * FROM admin_wp.wp_8_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30 LIMIT 0, 10 "
```

If you want to use a here-doc, you put it after the command:

```
mysql -u ***** -p***** admin-wp <<EOFMYSQL
SELECT * 
FROM admin_wp.wp_8_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30
LIMIT 0, 10 
EOFMYSQL
```

Also, your SQL syntax was wrong. `LIMIT` has to come after `WHERE`. BTW, it doesn't make much sense to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` -- it will just pick any random 10 rows from the results.

Comment: mysql -u ***** -p***** admin-wp <<EOFMYSQL
    DELETE FROM wp_8_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 30
    LIMIT 0, 10 
    EOFMYSQL

gives me ERROR 1064 (42000) at line1: You have an error in your SQL sytax;